# Syntax error with foreign key in add foreign key

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

When I use alter and add statement I get an error

The SQL code is:

```
create table lecturer (

    lecturer_id int primary key,

    lecturer_name varchar(20)

    )
create table course_lecturer(

          date varchar(20)

      )
alter table course_lecturer

add foreign key(lecturer_id) references lecturer(lecturer_id)
```

The error boils down to:

> Near "foreign key": syntax error

I want to link between lecturer table and course_lecturer

Comment: The course_lecturer table needs a lecturer_id column before you can add the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table lecturer (
    lecturer_id int primary key,
    lecturer_name varchar(20)
    )

create table course_lecturer(
          //U need here a lecturer_id for bind the fk 
          date varchar(20)
      )
alter table course_lecturer

add foreign key(lecturer_id) references lecturer(lecturer_id)
```

Hope this help!